# Different output with node and "Run code snippet" from stackoverflow in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a file in c:\jsdev\ folder called `script.js`

with this source code:

```js
const arr = [3, 'myStr', 5, 7];
arr.foo = 'hello';

for (let i in arr) {
  console.log(i); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo"
}

console.log(arr);
```

When I run this in cmd

```
c:\jsdev>node script.js
```

I get following output

```
0
1
2
3
foo
[ 3, 'myStr', 5, 7, foo: 'hello' ]
```

[Picture of my cmd shell in Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoVdI.png)

But when I press the `Run code snippet` (try it out now in stackoverflow), it just outputs

```
[ 3, 'myStr', 5, 7 ]
```

Comment: The gist is that you shouldn't add properties to an *array*. Use an object for that.

Comment: There's no standard for how `console.log()` works. Chrome doesn't display array properties, node.js does.

Comment: Thank you very much for this observations between chrome and node.js !!

Comment: see: [Why doesn't the code snippet's console display string-key properties of an array?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385652/why-doesnt-the-code-snippets-console-display-string-key-properties-of-an-array)